# Why does the longer code does not exceed the time limit whereas the shorter exceeds the time limit?

Tags: python, time, time-complexity, complexity-theory

It is a simple code for counting the number of common factors two numbers have . How is the first code not exceeding the tie limit while the second is exceeding the time limit.
**FIRST**

```
from math import sqrt
def gcd(a, b): 
      
    if a == 0: 
        return b 
    return gcd(b % a, a) 

def commDiv(a, b): 
      
    # find GCD of a, b 
    n = gcd(a, b) 
  
    # Count divisors of n 
    result = 0
    for i in range(1,int(sqrt(n))+1): 
  
        # if i is a factor of n 
        if n % i == 0: 
  
            # check if divisors are equal 
            if n/i == i: 
                result += 1
            else: 
                result += 2

    return result


if __name__ == "__main__":
        a , b = map(int,input().split())
        print(commDiv(a, b))
```

**SECOND**

```
a , b = map(int,input().split())
if a>b:
        small = b
        big = a
else:
        small = a
        big = b
c = 0
for i in range(1,small+1):
    if small%i == 0 and big%i == 0:
            c = c + 1
print(c)
```

Comment: If think the key lies in number of iteration your forloop is making.

Answer (score 0):

The number of CPU cycles (speed of execution) depends more on the algorithm than it does on the length of your code.

In this particular case, your **SECOND** solution has a loop that repeats `small` times. So, for, let's say, pair (1200, 700) it will repeat 700 times.

Your **FIRST** solution starts by finding a GCD of the two numbers. "Most often" it is going to be much smaller than either number (unless `a` is divisible by `b` or vice versa). And then it only repeats `sqrt(gcd)` times, which ends up being an even smaller number of iterations. For the same pair, the GCD is 100, so the loop will repeat `sqrt(100) == 10` times. Ten vs seven hundred.

Even for the worst case scenario, where `a` is divisible by `b`, say, (300000, 10000), your **FIRST** solution will iterate `sqrt(10000) == 100` times, while your **SECOND** will iterate 10000 times.

**Edit**: have to note that the GCD calculation does take up a few CPU cycles itself, but the way it is implemented, it will recurse in large steps and have a smaller impact on the total time.